# Change SPI pins in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid, spi

I read in the documentation that SPI pins are 10, 11, 12, 13, but my board has only few ports, so I can't use those specific ports, and I'd like to change them.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change your SPI pins, it is the hardware configuration of your micro (ATmega328p)...

[image]

The only option you have is to have free PIN 11,12 and 13 for the SPI communication and configure your slave selection Pin on an other free digital I/O pin.

You can also consider using an arduino MEGA if you need more I/O.